# Meaning of "to be" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> "We know it to be a drug"

Here, what does it mean by "*to be*" in this sentence? I know that it is a active infinitive sentence. But my question is what is the full form of "*to be*" here? If you say the full form of "*to be*" in this sentence is "*is*" then if I replace "*to be*" by "*is*", it will make no sense like:

> "We know it is a drug"

Comment: *We know it to be true.*  We know it is true.

Comment: It's a somewhat dated/formal usage in your exact context (younger and/or more relaxed speakers will tend to prefer *We know it **is** a drug).* But it's still completely natural in, say, *I **want** you **to be** quiet*. The precise syntax of verbs of volition / perception such as ***think, know, want*** can get quite complicated - partly because those are *exactly* the kind of words relevant to contexts where a speaker often *deliberately* (but not necessarily *consciously*) wishes to be a little vague (as to exactly what they think or want).

Comment: Tᴚoɯɐuo,
According to your answer if I say "We know it is true" Then my question is what is "is true" here.Is it a phrase?

Answer (score 1):

> "We know it to be a drug"

*It* is there because we don't know what it is, but we know certain aspects of whatever it is.

> We know it is a drug

*It* is a real instance of an object.  Meaning it actually existed somewhere or exists now, or we have one of "it".

> We know it to be a drug

*It* is NOT a real instance of an object.  We have not seen whatever "it" is yet.

We'd say this if we are trying to deduce something from reports, for example.  E.g. "I've received reports of this strange thing called Krokodil. I've never actually seen it.  I don't know what it is, really.  We know it to be a drug."