# The use of "to be" instead of "is"

Tags: grammar

It was in this [video](https://youtu.be/8TN3ebiVPNw). It is at 8 minute and 13 second. Here it goes:

> But could we consider the combination of all these unnoticed factors **to be** compromising Jerry's free will.

Would not it be grammatical to say "...the combination of all these factors **is** 
compromising Jerry's free will"? And How is called this grammar structure?

Comment: It's grammatical either way.  "Could we consider **that** X **is** Y?"  vs.  "Could we consider X **to be** Y"?  No idea what it's called, but I'd guess at some kind of *participle phrase*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "to be" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167044/meaning-of-to-be-in-this-sentence)

Comment: the right order for negative interrogative is: Wouldn't it be grammatical. And yes, of course, the combination of all these factors is compromising X's free will. However, there is already a question: Could we consider x? Can you consider this to be a short answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words like *consider*, and *judge* can take two different types of clause as their object.

They can take a non-finite clause, with a "to"-infinitive:

> We consider X to be Y.

They can take a finite clause, optionally introduced by "that"

> We consider [that] X is Y.

There is no difference in meaning, but the non-finite construction is fairly formal, more used in writing than in speech.